# How does the following lambda function work in place of 'itemgetter' in Python's sort function?

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I have this code, and it sorts my list by the its second item - but what is the lambda function actually doing?

```
 sorted_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)
```

I get the basics properties of them; they are anonymous, disposable functions - but I don't see what's going on here. Is it taking `x` as a parameter and returning `x[1]`?

Comment: `sort` calls `key` when doing comparisons.  That is, when sort is about to compare two values in a sequence, it uses `key` to handle the logic in returning the values from each element in the sequence.

Comment: Not quite: `key` is guaranteed to be called only once per element in the sequence, regardless of how many comparisons using that element are made. This is what makes the key function superior to the `cmp` method it supersedes, which *was* called at every comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"Is it taking `x` as a parameter and returning `x[1]`?"* That's exactly what it's doing, yes.

Written as a regular function that lambda function would look like this:

```
def sortkey(x):
    return x[1]
```

So that function is equivalent to `operator.itemgetter(1)`.

And since the purpose of a key function is to return the sort key, that resulting key (the second element in the sequence `x`) is what the list will be sorted on.

Answer (score 3):

That is what it does. It never hurts to experiment in the shell. Lambda expressions are expressions. They can be assigned to variables and tested that way:

```
>>> f = lambda x:x[1]
>>> f([4,6,2])
6
```

You can also use it directly:

```
>>> (lambda x:x[1])([4,6,2])
6
```